# SD card ACMD42 command

Tags: microcontroller, sd

According to SD card datasheets, there is an internal pull-up resistor on the DAT3 line, and we can use this line to detect the card. Additionally, the ACMD42 command is described that it is used to disable this pull-up resistor. However, when I look for some SD device driver code I see that they do not send this command.

Is sending the ACMD42 command a must or a recommendation? What happens if we don't send this command?

Comment: Is this two questions? They don't seem related.

Comment: my explanation had been deleted by mistake.Thanks for the notice! @Austin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right that according to the specification the DAT3 line has a number of uses.

In SD mode it is the fourth data line and in SPI mode it's the chip select signal.  The Physical Layer Simplified Specification Version 4.10 says:

> At power up this line has a 50KOhm pull up enabled in the card.

And goes on to say (emphasis mine):

> For Card detection, the host detects that the line is pulled high. This pull-up **should be disconnected by the user**, during regular data transfer, with SET_CLR_CARD_DETECT (ACMD42) command

So the specification explicitly states that ACMD42 should be used to disconnect the pull up resistor.

What would happen if the host doesn't do this?  There are three scenarios:

1. In 1 wire SD mode this pin is (probably) unused, so maybe it would make no difference.
2. In 4 wire SD mode this will be a data line, so whatever is driving the bus will need to overcome the 50k pull up.  Maybe this would be a problem at high speed.
3. In SPI mode this is the chip select pin.  You are unlikely to run into problems toggling it at the speeds involved.

I can only guess about SD mode as that part of the specification isn't public.

Note that a large amount of online code for SD cards is fairly poor quality.  There are various parts of the specification that are quite clear about what a host must do at various points.  These are typically simplified away in public code.  However this code will still work 90% of the time.

So in summary: the specification says you should disconnect the resistor but if you don't you probably won't run into problems in SPI mode.

Comment: I was thinking similar things with you. Your explanation makes me sure. Thank you @David!